# Getting event 57:The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur

Tags: windows-7, vmware, ntfs, truecrypt, acronis-trueimage

I have a weird issue with my Windows7 desktop. There are two separate disks, C: (system) and D:. Both are encrypted with TrueCrypt.

Every once in awhile I am getting following issue: all writes to disk D: do not go through. There is no indication that writes do not succeed, it looks like files are being written, but they are not. Following event is being reported to system log:

```
The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur.
<Provider Name="Ntfs" /> 
<EventID Qualifiers="32772">57</EventID> 
<Level>3</Level> 
<Task>2</Task> 
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
```

Reboot fixes the issue. All files on D: drive are reverted back to the state when first one of those errors occur

Aside from TrueCrypt, I have following software installed, which could be suspect:

- Acronis TrueImage Home 2012
- VMWare Player 5.0.1

Before answering, please consider what this is not:

a) NOT Hardware issue. I replaced both drives recently, and the problem stays
b) NOT removable drive problem. Both drives are fixed
c) NOT O/S corruption. I have re-installed O/S and the problem started re-occurring
d) NOT antivirus. After re-installing O/S I have not installed any antivirus

Have anyone experienced this before, and What could that possibly be?